# How to efficiently generate a unique combination of first and last name given an array of full names

Tags: ruby

I'm having a bit of difficulty with a problem I'm having. I have an array of names like so:

```
[Brutananadilewski, Carl]
[Crews, Xander]
[Cartman, Eric]
[Rubio, Daniel]
[Daniels, Julie]
etc. etc.
```

What I need to do is to create a list of unique names from this list without having first and last names repeated. So I would have the following as a result:

```
[Brutananadilewski, Daniel]
[Crews, Erix]
[Cartman, Xander]
[Rubio, Carl]
[Jill, Daniels]
```

The problem I'm having is trying to do this efficiently. My first instint was to use permutation and here is a snippet from the ruby docs

```
a.permutation(2).to_a #=> [[1,2],[1,3],[2,1],[2,3],[3,1],[3,2]]
```

The problem is having the following from that example `[[1,2],[1,3]]`

Theoretically if this was a first/last name this wouldnt work. I couldn't have this:

`[Rubio Daniel, Rubio Julie, Rubio Eric]`

Has anyone dealt with this before? I'm having an awfully hard time with efficiency and just getting it to work. Help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: Seems like it'd be a lot easier to just split into two collections, shuffle them, and re-join. That wouldn't prevent getting back one of the original names, but that's what random means. If you need to explicitly prevent getting back an original then you'd need to have a set of "disallowed" combos and check against it, which would make a pick-and-remove operation easier.

Comment: Thanks so much Dave. You're comment really just helped me shift my thinking. Thank you very much, you saved me a long time in a rabbit hole.

Comment: Please show your array as a valid Ruby object, in part so that readers can cut-and-paste to execute their code. For example, `names = [[‘Brutananadilewski’, ‘Carl’], 
[‘Crews’, ‘Xander’],..]`.

Comment: This is an easy problem or a hard-ish problem, depending on whether there can be duplicate first or last names. For example, could your array of names also contain `[‘Palmer’, ‘Carl’]` or `[‘Hartman’, ‘Lois’]`? Please edit to clarify.

Comment: You’ve said nothing about randomness or other criteria for determining if a rearrangement is valid. For example, if `names` is your array of arrays of last and first names, is `names` itself a valid answer? If not, why not? Could a rearrangement contain an element of `names` (e.g., `[‘Crews’, ‘Xander’]`)? Lastly, your dark glasses need repair or replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`transpose`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Array.html#method-i-transpose) as [mentioned by 3limin4tor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57890238/how-to-efficiently-generate-a-unique-combination-of-first-and-last-name-given-an/57890468?noredirect=1#comment102203157_57890468), then [`shuffle`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Array.html#method-i-shuffle) and [`zip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Array.html#method-i-zip) as [mentioned by Dave Newton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57890238/how-to-efficiently-generate-a-unique-combination-of-first-and-last-name-given-an#comment102201998_57890238):

```
surnames, forenames = names.transpose

shuffled_forenames = forenames.shuffle
shuffled_names = shuffled_forenames.zip(surnames)
```

Comment: `surnames, forenames = names.transpose` See: [`Array#transpose`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Array.html#method-i-transpose)

Answer (score 1):

The desired outcome isn't entirely clear from the question, but if you're trying to create all combinations of first/last names and get a subset of those, you could also use `product` and `uniq` to get all the uniq combinations:

```
names = [
  %w(Brutananadilewski Carl),
  %w(Crews Xander),
  %w(Cartman Eric),
  %w(Rubio Daniel),
  %w(Daniels Julie)
]

surnames, forenames = names.transpose

all_name_combos = forenames.product(surnames).uniq
```

You could then use `shuffle` and `sample(INTEGER)` to get a subset of those name combinations

```
all_name_combos.shuffle.sample(5)
```